# Result.responseText undefined in JQuery, but available and working in firebug

Tags: jquery, json

I'm writing a function that returns a JSON object containing information from the Flickr API. 
the global variable data returns a json object in firebug's console, and data.responseText also prints out relevant information. However, calling jsonthing = data.responseText in the code results in something that is undefined.

Ultimately, I just want to use parseJSON(data.responseText) to make a JSON object, and amazingly enough it works in the firebug console, just not in the code.

any ideas?

```
$(function () {
  var apiKey = 'somekeyhere';
  data = $.getJSON(
    'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=' +
    apiKey + '&user_id=29096781@N02&format=json&per_page=5&nojsoncallback=1');
  hi = '2';
  jsonthing = data.responseText;
  jsonobj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
  $('#Test').html(data.toString());
  //$('#Test').html(data.photos.photo.title); 
});
```

Comment: The `responseText`would actually be the `data` returned, and as it's `getJSON` that data would already be parsed by jQuery, and you need to wait for the call to complete, so both answers below are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous, so you need to register a callback:

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    // Work with data
});
```

Comment: Thanks - what does asynchronous mean in this context?

Comment: @user1889096: It's non-blocking. Basically, instead of waiting for it to finish, the browser just starts the request and runs that function when it's finished.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need parseJSON. The result of the getJSON callback is already parsed into JS data structures